# How to identify iphones?

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone

I wrote a script that identifies desktop and made possible to have a great percentage of identifying android devices, each visitor a unique id.
However I am having difficulties with iPhone, it seems that their browsers have same characteristics.

Is anyone aware of a workaround on how to extract something unique from the device, client-side probably?

For now, I identify them by plugins, http headers, user-agent, resolution and colours.

Comment: have you looked at the countless number of [fingerprinting libraries](https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs) out there. All say that it is nearly impossible for iphone.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/danott/855078

Answer (score -4):

Iphones have their own user-agents. You can use a regular js check like this :

```
var agent = navigator.userAgent;

if ((agent.indexOf('iPhone') != -1) {

  //  Mycode

}
```